# How to get the memory usage of a process with Python?

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have the PID of a process of a Linux and I want to get the memory usage of that process using a Python script. Is it that possible? What module do I have to use?

Comment: have a look at psutil https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil

Comment: Use the module "Google" and type "How to get memory allocation of process Python"

Comment: Thank you so much @JamesKent